# Can I call Jesus "Rasool Allah"?

Tags: prophet-isa, aqidah

As Salam Aleikhum can I call Isha Rashool Allah or YA Rashool Allah as Muhammad Rashool Allah.because Isha is also my prophet as Muhammed is my prophet can I give same reference to Isha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jesus was a Prophet *and* a Messenger just like Moses and Muhammad, so yes you can call him رسول الله  and this is proven in the Quran:

> المسيح عيسى ابن مريم **رسول الله** وكلمته القاها الى مريم وروح منه
>
> *Al-Masihu `Isa Abnu Maryama **Rasulu Allah**i Wa Kalimatuhu 'Alqaha 'Ila Maryama Wa Ruhun Minhu*
>
> The Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, was a **messenger of Allah** and His word which He directed to Mary and a soul from Him.
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:171](https://quran.com/4/171)</sup>
>
> واذ قال عيسى ابن مريم يا بني اسراييل اني **رسول الله** اليكم مصدقا لما بين يدي من التوراة ومبشرا برسول ياتي من بعدي اسمه احمد
>
> *Wa Idh Qala Isa Abnu Maryama Ya Bani Isra'ila Inni **Rasulu Allah**i 'Ilaykum Musaddiqaan Lima Bayna Yadayya Mina At-Tawraati Wa Mubashiraan Birasulin Ya'ti Min Ba`di Asmuhu 'Ahmad*
>
> And [mention] when Jesus, the son of Mary, said, "O children of Israel, indeed I am the **messenger of Allah** to you confirming what came before me of the Torah and bringing good tidings of a messenger to come after me, whose name is Ahmad."
>
> <sup>[Quran 61:6](https://quran.com/61/6)</sup>

I'm not sure if you'd say "**ya** rasul-allah" unless you were talking to him.

Answer (score 0):

You could but in general we really refer to him as Isa (AS)
It’s fine so... I guess yes you could do that

But Isa (as) is not in front of us so it’s better not so say YA rasool Allah

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.
We Muslim are certain about that the result of our every actions depends on our Mind(Niyaat).
So if u call him "Rasool Allah" with the proper & accurate status & position that we find by the Quranic Verses & authentic Hadiths,that is pretty well.
We Muslims are of wide minded and try to follow the teachings of every prophet & messenger of Allah besides Muhammad(Pubh).
Obviously,our main core beleif is Quran what Muhammad (Pubh) got from Allah(SAW) .And as a direction of Quran we try to follow various teachings from our Prophhets.
Likely,Patience from Noh,Ayub.
Sacrifice from Ibrahim and so on.

Answer (score -4):

No.  Reason is we were send a rasuul (Mohammad ibn Abdullah ibn Abdulmutalib ibn Hashim ) SAW.  He is representative for Isa ibn Maryama AS.  Isa was not sent for all creation. Therefore his message/mission was not completed. Until new prophet to complete the cycle and Isa to return to only confirm that he is Muslim.  So Rasuul lulaah is only applicable to the latest 1 which is the 1 you follow.